# how can I detect if an address contained a contract that called selfdestruct?

Tags: web3js, selfdestruct

I would like to create a `web3`-based JS function like this:

`function hasSelfDestructed(address) {
  if (... address was a contract, but has called selfdestruct ...)
    return true
  else
    return false
}`

If a contract has called `selfdestruct`, its code will be empty, or `web3.eth.getCode(address) === '0x'`. However, non-contract addresses also have empty code.

You can see a contract's code at some point in the past with `web3.eth.getCode(address, blockNumber)` (if you have a non-pruned full node). But short of querying all previous blocks, how would I know what past block to examine?

I suppose I could scan every transaction since block 0 and see if any transaction creates the contract. The transaction receipt has the `contractAddress` field to help with this. Whenever I see an attempt at contract creation, I could see if it succeeded and yielded any code at the address.

Is there another way?

Comment: I don't think there is a way without querying the previous blocks. Maybe you can use Etherscan's API to query the transactions faster.